# Testing-librairy : How to check a text when it is returned by a function

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a react component which displays a text of which some words may change depending on the value of the object

```
 import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
 import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
 import { Card, Col, Row } from 'react-bootstrap';

 function RenderPressMedia(props: any) {
   const { t } = useTranslation();
   const [pressPlanned, setPressPlanned] = useState<any[]>([]);
   useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.pressPlannedData) return;
    setPressPlanned(props.pressPlannedData);
   }, [props.pressPlannedData]);

   const renderMedia = (media: string) => {
    switch (media) {
  case 'PHONE':
    return t('press.media.phone');
  case 'LETTER':
    return t('press.media.letter');
  case 'EMAIL':
    return t('press.media.email');
  case 'SMS':
    return t('press.media.sms');
}
};

const renderPress = (media: string) => {
return (
  <>
    {t(`press.text`, {
      media: renderMedia(media),
    })}
  </>
);
 };

return (
 <Row>
  {pressPlanned.length > 0 &&
    pressPlanned.map((press, index) => (
      <Col lg={12} className="col-main" key={index}>
        <Card>
          <Card.Body>
            <ul className="d-flex flex-row m-0 list-unstyled align-items-center">
              <li aria-label="Reminder to do or reminder for today">
                {renderPress(press.media)}
              </li>
            </ul>
          </Card.Body>
        </Card>
      </Col>
    ))}
 </Row>
 );
 }

export default RenderPressMedia;
```

`renderPressMedia` function returns a translation which will change depending on the variable sent.
Component that works very well.

But when I want to perform a test on this component with `testing-library`, I cannot verify the content returned by the `pressMedia` function.

Here is the test carried out.

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
 import RenderPressMedia from '../render-press-media';

 const data: any[] = [
  {
   id: 65,
   media: 'LETTER',
   firstPlannedDate: '2021-09-03',
   plannedDate: '2021-09-03',
   comment: 'autogenerated',
   createdDate: '2021-08-27T09:43:52',
   lastModifiedDate: '2021-08-27T09:43:52',
  },
 ];
 describe('<RenderPressMedia/>', () => {
  it('should display an render press media with data', () => {
   //given
   render(<RenderPressMedia pressPlannedData={data} />);
   //then
   expect(screen.getByText(/letter/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
 });
 });
```

The test consists in verifying the presence of the word '**letter**' returned by the `pressMedia` function

```
expect(screen.getByText(/letter/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
```

But unfortunately I got an error message

```
  Unable to find an element with the text: /courrier/i. This could be because the 
  text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function 
  for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

  Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
  <body>
   <div>
     <div
     class="row"
      >
     <div
       class="col-main col-lg-12"
     >
    <div
      class="card"
    >
      <div
        class="card-body"
      >
        <ul
          class="d-flex flex-row m-0 list-unstyled align-items-center"
        >
          <li
            aria-label="Reminder to do or reminder for today"
          >
            press.text
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /courrier/i. 
       This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you 
       can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.
```

the `pressMedia` function in testingLibrairy does not return its contents so impossible to verify the presence of the word **letter**, return value is **press.text**

If you have a solution to correct this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like, it's happening because you're using the i18n functions, but also it's mocked and just gives back to you the text which received as a parameter.

Any case, in this case, what you're doing is pretty well. But also you're testing the translation. So, it can be more complicated and hard to maintain.

So, I'd recommend to test if it's using the correct media would be something like:

```js
<li aria-label="Reminder to do or reminder for today" data-testid="component" data-media={press.media}>
  {renderPress(press.media)}
</li>
```

And in the testing part:

```js
expect(screen.getByTestId('component')).toHaveAttribute('data-media', data.media);
```

In this case, ignoring the language, You know which kind of media has your component.

I created this github repo as example:

- Repo: https://github.com/joseglego/test-testing-library/
- Component: https://github.com/joseglego/test-testing-library/blob/main/src/RenderPressMedia.js
- Test: https://github.com/joseglego/test-testing-library/blob/main/src/RenderPressMedia.test.js
- Specific commit: https://github.com/joseglego/test-testing-library/commit/f3c222f92313c909c8d4a1f359daf01bdd0f880d

Basically, that test is running on my local.

Comment: @joselego I think the solution is not very far, if I apply the solution expect(rect).toHaveAttribute('data-media', 'letter'), I end up with the following answer Expected the element to have attribute:
  data-media="letter"
Received:
  data-media="[object Object]"

Comment: Did you solve it? I can try it!

Comment: I updated the answer, including one specific commit, test file, and component file. It's already working. Let me know.

Comment: @joselego Great, thank you very much it works perfectly. A big thank you for your investment. If you are not far from where I live, I would offer you a drink ;)

Comment: Thanks so much! But, no problem! Was a pleasure!